# Type mismatch error trying to call wmi function from within xslt loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xsl template loop (recursive) which calls a VBScript function that takes one parameter which represents the physical hard drive number and retrieves drive information:

```
<xsl:template name="for.loop.Drives">
<xsl:param name="i" select ="0" />
<xsl:param name="count" />

<!--begin_: Line_by_Line_Output -->
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
    <xsl:value-of select="nunit2report2:GetDiskDrives($i)"/>
</xsl:if>

<!--begin_: RepeatTheLoopUntilFinished-->
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
  <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Drives">
    <xsl:with-param name="i">
      <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="count">
      <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

The VBScript function (which I verified works):

```
Function GetDiskDrives(drivenumber)

      strComputer = "."

      objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
      colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")

      'For Each objItem in colItems
      DiskDriveInfo = DiskDriveInfo  & "Name: " & colItems.ItemIndex(drivenumber).Name & _ 
      " -- Model: " & colItems.ItemIndex(drivenumber).Model &  _ 
      " -- Status: " & colItems.ItemIndex(drivenumber).Status &  _ 
      " -- Size: " & Int(colItems.ItemIndex(drivenumber).Size /(1073741824)) & " GB" & _ 
      " -- Number of Partitions: " & colItems.ItemIndex(drivenumber).Partitions
      'Next

      GetDiskDrives = DiskDriveInfo

End Function
```

The error returned is a type mismatch.  It has to do with the $i passed in to the function:

```
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
    <xsl:value-of select="nunit2report2:GetDiskDrives($i)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

When I do this, it works, but I'm explicitly passing in 1.

```
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
    <xsl:value-of select="nunit2report2:GetDiskDrives(1)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I tried converting the passed in $i to an integer in the VBScript using

```
drivenum = CInt(drivenumber)
```

but the cast above returns the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'XPathDocumentNavigator' to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Anyone know how I can get this call right?  I'm using xslt 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="nunit2report2:GetDiskDrives(number($i))"/>
```

Comment: That's the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Dimitre suggested, if you change

```
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
  <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Drives">
    <xsl:with-param name="i">
      <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="count">
      <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

into

```
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
  <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Drives">
    <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

the problem might go away or at least your script function then receives a double number that the script can then easily convert into an integer if needed for the WMI API.

Your current code is not only longer to write but unnecessarily passed around result tree fragments where all you want is passing around number values.